# Can someone help me with an exercise? C++ Lists

Tags: c++, list

Ive got an exercise due to tommorow and Ive got completely no idea how to do it, even though I know how to add to list, delete an element from list ( last or first ), or display a list, maybe its because I only know how to do it with one variable in struct.

sorry if my translation is not the best but Im translating the exercise from polish.

> 1.We have a structure
>
> struct point {
> double x, y;
> };
>
> Create a function that creats lists of consisting of n points

Then after it

> 2. Using the list created in previous exercise, create a function that prints on the screen coordinates of points lying inside the given circle. Pointer for the beginning of the list and defining values transfer as function parameters.

I was trying to do it alone but as of now Ive got completely no idea how to approach this. I think as for the first one, I should create a list, head and tail and next,then constructor that sets head and tail to NULL, then function that adds elements to list, then in main ask user for the 'n' value and create for loop with that function.

After that, Ive got completely no idea what to do next. I may have been wrong even until now.

Sorry if I waste your time reading this, I just hope someone can help me and explain me what to do.

Sorry if its also not the place to ask for that kind of help, Im kinda new to all of this.

Comment: This is not a site to help with exercises, but it here to help if you're stuck. But for that you need to explain what you've tried, what your problem is precisely, and code that you've tried.

Comment: ***because I only know how to do it with one variable in struct.*** There is not really a big difference with more than 1 variable in a struct. Why is this causing you an issue? Please show your code and explain what problem you have with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separate the concept of data from the links.

```
struct Node
{
  Point data;
  Node * p_previous;
  Node * p_next;
};
```

Later on you may want to make the list into a *template* so that you can pass any type for the data field.

To get the coordinates from a `Node`:

```
  Point coordinate = p_node->data;
  double x_ordinate = coordinate.x;
  double y_ordinate = coordinate.y;
```

*Off-topic:  screen coordinates should be integers, not floating point. Usually, pixels are hole element, I haven't heard of real partial pixels.*